# Video hardware error

Tags: windows-7, graphics-card, hardware-failure

I just used the Windows Solution tool and I had 4 errors that stated this

Problem: Video hardware error
Files that help describe the problem:

WD-20130630-2216.dmp

sysdata.xml

WERInternalMetadata.xml

Does anyone know what I can do, to fix this? I tried to update drivers for my Radeon HD 5670 but I am on the latest driver patch, well windows states that. Could anyone help me at all?

Comment: That error tells us nothing without the memory dump and log files.

Comment: Update the graphic card driver, BIOS and check that the RAM is fine.